# Minify nodejs templates real time

Tags: node.js, webpack, handlebars.js

I am building a nodejs app using Handlebars as my template engine. I have a template like this one (template.hbs):

```
<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
         {{ my_var }}
      </body>
    </html>
```

I wonder if I can work (write code) with this file while using on node a minified version ( that will be compiled and delivered for the user ) like this (minified_template.hbs):

```
<html><head></head><body>{{ my_var }}</body></html>
```

I mean, I would like some program to be running all time, watching for changes on "template.hbs" and generating "minified_template.hbs". This way I can save bandwidth and money. Is there such a program that can do it? I've heard of Webpack but after searching on google I am still no sure it can do this kind of job. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to my question. It's name is "Gulp":

Install nodejs, then run on commandline:

```
npm install -g gulp
npm install --save-dev gulp-minify-html
```

create a file named "gulpfile.js" as:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifyHtml = require("gulp-minify-html");

gulp.task('minify-views', function () {
    gulp.src('./views/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyHtml())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./views_minified'));
});


gulp.task('watch-views', function () {
    gulp.src('./views/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyHtml())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./views_minified'));

    gulp.watch(["./views/*.html"],['minify-views']);
});
```

Then, from commandline, run:

gulp watch-views

When anny file under the "views" folder is modified, it gets minified by gulp and saved with tha same name to the folder named "views_minified".